# how to use macro in ftl

Tags: freemarker

I have full of confusion in implementing the macro and functions in ftl.
can any one please add some useful information.

```
  and what is the difference between macro and function in ftl
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The difference between macros and functions: macros are for generating markup (or other long text) and for flow-control and side-effects in general. Functions are for calculating other kind of values, including short plain text, and usually has no side-effects. These are reflected by that fact that macros has no return value, they just directly print to the output. Also the output of macros is not escaped by #escape. That's also why they look similar to HTML tags, while `${myFunction()}` doesn't.

Other than that, what are you confused about? I assume you have found the FreeMarker Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer how to use macros in FTL :)

### Input-smooks.Json:

```
 { 
        "title": "Payment Received", 
        "firstName": "vijay", 
        "lastName": "dwivedi", 
        "accountId": "123", 
        "paymentId": "456", 
        "accounts": [ 
            { 
                "accountId": "1111", 
                "paymentId": "1112" 
            }, 
            { 
                "accountId": "2111", 
                "paymentId": "2112" 
            }, 
            { 
                "accountId": "3111",
                "paymentId": "3112" 
            } 
        ] 
    }
```

### Smook-config.xml file:

Define macros once and use as function whenever required

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
    xmlns:json="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/json-1.1.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd">

    <params>
        <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
        <param name="default.serialization.on">false</param>
    </params>

    <json:reader rootName="json" keyWhitspaceReplacement="_">
        <json:keyMap>
            <json:key from="date&amp;time" to="date_and_time" />
        </json:keyMap>
    </json:reader>

    <resource-config selector="json">
        <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
    </resource-config>

    <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="json">
        <ftl:template>
            <!-- 
            <#macro PopulateTasks task_list>
                <#list task_list as att1>
                    "accountId": "${att1.accountId}"
                    "paymentId": "${att1.paymentId}"
                </#list>
            </#macro>

            <@PopulateTasks json.accounts.element/>

             -->
        </ftl:template>
    </ftl:freemarker>

</smooks-resource-list>



  public static void main(String[] args) throws SmooksException, IOException, SAXException {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Smooks smooks = new Smooks("src/main/resources/smooks-config.xml");

        try {
            smooks.filterSource(new StreamSource(new 
            FileInputStream("src/main/resources/input_smooks.json")), new 
            StreamResult(System.out));

        } finally {
            smooks.close();
        }
    }
```

`<@PopulateTasks json.accounts.element/>` this is the way to call macros